# How to control the overlap in `Epilog->Inset[]`?

Tags: plotting, graphics

## Problem

Take an example as follows:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Clock"}];
plt = Graphics[{Red, Arrowheads[.1], Thickness[.02] , 
           Table[Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Sin[i], Cos [i]}}], {i, 0, Pi, 1}]},
           Epilog -> Inset[img]]
```

which produce an image as:

[image: test image]

## Question

I want to overlay the `img` **under** the arrows, not **above** them. It's best to use `Epilog->Inset[]` method.

Thank you.

## Background

I have researched `Overlay[]`. It can configure the layers,but it fails to set the position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Prolog->Inset[..]` instead of the `Epilog`

Comment: Exactly!! That's the very thing I wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`Overlay`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Overlay.html) where the order of the list dictates the order of the layers.

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Clock"}];
plt = Graphics[{Red, Arrowheads[.1], Thickness[.02], 
   Table[Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Sin[i], Cos[i]}}], {i, 0, Pi, 1}]}]

Overlay /@ Permutations[{img, plt, Text[Style["text", Blue]]}, {3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thank you. but I found that `Overlay[]` does not have an option to configure the position of an inset. Do you have any ideas about setting the position?

Comment: @PureLine If you had provided, in your question, a particular example of the alignment you need, I would have shown how to use `Alignment` option.

Comment: thanks to your hint. I have managed it. `Overlay[{plot, image},{2,1}, Alighment->{x,y}]`, which will put the `image` above `plot`.